# Is it me or are GRM tools really expensive?

Tags: plug-ins, spectral

There are some pretty cool Things in here, but I feel like a lot of these do what Michael Norris spectral magic plug-ins do. They are free. I'm sure it is in no small part due to my very limited bag of tricks. It just seems that the price is very high for these. Thoughts from users or from those that chose other products? On OS X.

Answer (score 2):

They are expensive, because they're a rarity in the plug-in market. I.e. it just happens to be that they've got a set of plug-ins that barely anyone else has considered replicating or just hasn't done it as well as the GRM plug-ins (there are some plug-ins that may be "sort of" the same, but not the same. The Michael Norris plug-in pack is exceptional in the sense that it's been made available completely free, when it could be as well sold for e.g. 50% of the price of the GRM pack, and people would probably buy it.). In the case that the product is unique or a rarity it's very easy to set a premium price for the product.

For the same reason Pro Tools is expensive, because "it's considered to be" an exceptional piece of software (used by everyone etc.), thus a premium price.

Answer (score 2):

They may be somewhat expensive, but I could never live without them. I've gotten more sounds out of, say, GRM Freeze than just about any other plug-in I own (and I own quite a few), and while I haven't quite fallen for the new spectral tools, classics like GRM Delays, GRM Doppler and GRM PitchAccum are, to me, indispensable. I also really like their Bandpass filter, and have gotten some pretty unusual stuff out of GRM Contrast.

In short: I think I'd just about pay the full price for Freeze alone. ;)

Comment: me too: love FREEZE!


Answer (score 2):

How do you decide what a fair price is for a set of plugins? Comparing them to a free set isn't really fair, as there is no obligation for the developer to update or support free plugs... Plugins are an investment, ideally you buy the ones that you will actually use and at least with software as far as accounting goes they are a good tax write off! And as others have said, there is a lot of unique value in GRM Tools. I've been using them since when they were TDM only, now THAT was cost prohibitive!!

Also GREAT to see they have abandoned iLok! So far it only applies to new purchases but I understand it will be applied to previously purchased plugs too! Excellent - good riddance iLok!

Comment: Yea, I'm not looking at it objectively, and like I said, i could very well just not be getting things that are that cool out of it due to lack of time spent. The more I hear about how people here feel about them, it seems to be one of those "every track" type of tools, so i suppose it is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I've got to agree with the consesus here, and say that they may be expensive, but they are worth it.

They can give you the ability to create some truly unique sounds that can not be created using other plug ins.

Their unique take on the automation settings as well deserve a mention here too, as they make it so easy to glide between snapshots and create sounds with more movement/variation in them.

Amazing stuff.

Comment: I agree that the snapshot glide design is where they really excel.

Answer (score 1):

GRM Tools' price is based on provided value more than anything. It's not you, they are expensive.
Much like Waves, they are standard in the industry's toolset. Unlike Waves they don't do promotions every other week. I find GRM crashtastic.. for that alone they should cost less. Very difficult to find equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

I have long adored the GRM Tools Classic Tools plug-ins. Bandpass has a wonderful resonance at the cutoff frequencies and is very useful. Doppler is still the best for automating movements. Shuffle is a very nice texture-izer. Freeze is unique. Among the more recent releases I've been using Contrast a lot lately too. They are well worth their cost, the Classic Tools from dontcrack.com are $289.